# names in list save in string separated commas vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

there is file upload control.. when we select file by clicking on browse and then click on upload then file name with extension i.e. abc.doc is  display in listbox... then when we use again same file upload and click on browse and select another file then file is display i.e. xyz.pdf in listbox.. so there is two files abc.doc and xyz.doc in listbox .. **so i want these names in string with separated commas like this abc.doc,xyz.pdf** .. because further i want to insert that names in table

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim DocumentName As String = ListBox1.Items.Item(i).Text

        'Dim Docextension As String = ""
        'Docextension = Path.GetExtension(fileUpEx.PostedFile.FileName)

        Dim Docextension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(DocumentName)
        ' Label4.Text = Convert.ToString("Uploaded File Extension: ") & Docextension


        'Dim Document As Byte() = New Byte(fileUpEx.PostedFile.ContentLength - 1) {}
        'Document = fileUpEx.FileBytes

        Dim Document As Byte() = New Byte(DocumentName.Length - 1) {}
        fileUpEx.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(Document, 0, DocumentName.Length)



        Dim strKeyName_e() As String = {"DocumentName", "DocType", "Document", "DocExtension"}
        Dim objKeyVal_l() As Object = {DocumentName, 7, Document, Docextension}
        structDb = objDataSet.ExecSP("tbl", "spupload_file", strKeyName_e, objKeyVal_l)

        Dim DocName = DocumentName.ToString().Split(",")


    Next
```

i want documentname with separated commas in docname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim commaSeparatedFileNames =  String.Join(",",ListBox1.Items.Select(function(x)=>x.Text))
```